# Almost equal table with different running time

Tags: sql, oracle, join, sql-execution-plan

I’m using oracle. I have two table A and B
Table A has 8000 rows and 5 five columns
Table B has 5500 rows and same 5 columns
All of 5500 rows in table B are contained in Table A and they are the same

I have a query like

```
With t1 as (select distinct(id) from table A/B)
,T2 as (select a.id, c.value, d.value from Table A/B a
Join table c c on “conditions”
Join table d d on “conditions”
) select * from t2
```

So the query with Table A works excellent but with Table B it freezes for eternity.
Data types and other properties are  equal in table A and table A.

Where should i look for the problem?
I tried to explain plan but differences only in row “PX PARTITION HASH JOIN-FILTER” in Table A and “PX BLOCK ITERATOR ADAPTIVE” in table B

Comment: Post the actual plans.  Are there indexes on either A or B?  My first guess would be that the statistics on one or the other table are out of date.

Comment: Addition to the above: note that actual execution plan may be different from `explain` command output, so you need to gather the former (for example with EM or `dbms_sql_monitor`)